# Is there a way to create lightbox style galleries in asciidoc

Tags: codenameone, asciidoc, asciidoctor

We use asciidoc for our [blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/) and it's pretty powerful/pretty for the most part. But embedding a set of images is still "ugly" to say the least.

For that part of the site we don't need the PDF export so I was wondering if I can use something similar to lightbox JavaScript gallery with asciidoc?

I know I can embed HTML/JavaScript and just write the code for that. I'm looking for something "simpler" and more standard so we don't need to copy/paste boilerplate between posts.

Comment: I'm using anotora at work currently and that also uses asciidoc, did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: No, even simple image handling is a pain. I'm surprised this doesn't exist